# Copy Range repeated with offset

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to copy a range (Rows) repeated several times in VBA, where I know the name of the starting cell and the size of the range.

```
Sub test()
  Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long, a As Long, b As Long
  a = Sheets("sd").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For x = 1 To a
     If Worksheets("sd").Cells(x, 2) = "58117552" Then
      Sheets("sd").Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, 2).Offset(13, 0)).entireRows.Copy
      Sheets("sheet1").Activate
      Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
      Sheets("sheet1").Paste
      Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, but I don't know the correct way to select this range

Thanks for help

Comment: Why doesn't it work - code error or incorrect output?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: I getting an error message at:
Sheets("sd").Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, 2).Offset(13, 0)).entireRows.Copy

Comment: It should be `EntireRow`

Comment: i have removed Entirerow, i got only the first range and also i got an error message at the same line

Comment: *i got an error message at the same line*
How did that error message read? We cannot see your screen.

Comment: Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

That offset(13) is a bit confusing, but here is your code with the selects removed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("sd")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With sh
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To a
            If .Cells(x, 2) = "58117552" Then
                .Cells(x, 2).Offset(13, 0).EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your code but i got only the 13rd row 
I am searching to copy all rows (13 Rows) and also the other rows because the are repeated on the excel table
Thank you for your help

Comment: That's why I said the "Offset(13) was a bit confusing. You will havr to show how the layout is in your original question, possibly supply a screen shot of the layout.

Comment: Can you tell me please how can i insert an image here